# Variable reuse in C

Tags: c

The code I'm looking at is this:

```
for (i = 0; i < linesToFree; ++i ){
    printf("Parsing line[%d]\n", i);

    memset( &line, 0x00, 65 );
    strcpy( line, lines[i] );

    //get Number of words:
    int numWords = 0;

    tok = strtok(line , " \t");
    while (tok != NULL) {
        ++numWords;
        printf("Number of words is:  %d\n", numWords);
        println(tok);

        tok = strtok(NULL, " \t");
    }
}
```

My question centers around the use of `numWords`.  Does the runtime system reuse this variable or does it allocate a new `int` every time it runs through the `for` loop?  If you're wondering why I'm asking this, I'm a Java  programmer by trade who wants to get into HPC and am therefore trying to learn C.  Typically I know you want to *avoid* code like this, so this question is really exploratory.

I'm aware the answer is probably reliant upon the compiler... I'm looking for a deeper explanation than that.  Assume the compiler of your choice.

Comment: While control is inside the loop in which numwords is defined, numwords is reused; when control passes out of the loop, numwords ceases to exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what is called "block", "automatic" or "local" scope in C. It is a form of [lexical scoping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29#Lexical_scoping), i.e., a name refers to its local environment. In C, it is top down, meaning that it happens as the file is parsed and compiled and visible only after defined in the program. 
 When the variable goes out of scope, the lexical name is no longer valid (visible) and the memory may be reused.

The variable is declared in a local scope or a block defined by curly braces `{ /* block */ }`. This defines a whole group of C and C99 idioms, such as:

```
for(int i=0; i<10; ++i){    // C99 only. int i is local to the loop
    // do something with i 
}  // i goes out of scope here...
```

There are subtleties, such as:

```
 int x = 5;
 int y = x + 10; // this works

 int x = y + 10;
 int y = 5;      // compiler error
```

and:

```
int g;        // static by default and init to 0
extern int x; // defined and allocated elsewhere - resolved by the linker 
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int j=0;  // automatic by default  
    while (++j<=2) {
        int i=1,j=22,k=3;    // j from outer scope is lexically redefined
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
            int j=i+10,k=0;
            k++;             // k will always be 1 when printed below
            printf("INNER: i=%i, j=%i, k=%i\n",i,j,k);
        }
        printf("MIDDLE: i=%i, j=%i, k=%i\n",i,j,k);   // prints middle j
    }

    // printf("i=%i, j=%i, k=%i\n",i,j,k); compiler error
    return 0;
}
```

There are idiosyncrasies:

1. In K&R C, ANSI C89, and Visual Studio, All variables must be declared at the beginning of the function or compound statement (i.e., before the first statement)
2. In gcc, Variables may be declared anywhere in the function or compound statement and is only visible from that point on.
3. In C99 and C++, Loop variables may be declared in **for** statement and are visible until end of loop body.
4. In a loop block, the allocation is performed ONCE and the RH assignment (if any) is performed each time.

In the particular example you posted, you enquired about `int numWords = 0;` and if a new `int` is allocated each time through the loop. No, there is only one int allocated in a loop block, but the right hand side of the `=` is executed every time. This can be demonstrated so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

volatile time_t ti(void){
    return time(NULL);
}

void t1(void){
    time_t t1;
    for(int i=0; i<=10; i++){
        time_t t2=ti();    // The allocation once, the assignment every time
        sleep(1);
        printf("t1=%ld:%p t2=%ld:%p\n",t1,(void *)&t1,t2,(void *)&t2);
    }
}
```

Compile that with any **gcc** (clang, eclipse, etc) compatible compiler with optimizations off (`-O0`) or on. The address of t2 will always be the same.

Now compare with a recursive function:

```
int factorial(int n) {
    if(n <= 1)
        return 1;
    printf("n=%i:%p\n",n,(void *)&n);
    return n * factorial(n - 1);
}
```

The address of `n` will be different each time because a new automatic n is allocated with each recursive call.

Compare with an iterative version of factorial forced to used a loop-block allocation:

```
int fac2(int num) {
    int r=0;   // needed because 'result' goes out of scope
    for (unsigned int i=1; i<=num; i++) {
        int result=result*i;   // only RH is executed after the first time through
        r=result;
        printf("result=%i:%p\n",result,(void *)&result);  // address is always the same
    }
    return r;
}
```

In conclusion, you asked about `int numWords = 0;` inside the for loop. **The variable is reused in this example.**

The way the code is written, the programmer is relying on the RH of `int numWords = 0;` after the first to be executed and resetting the variable to 0 for use in the while loop that follows.

Comment: Your `fac2` example is C99, C1X only it should be noted. In straight gcc, the value of `result` is not initialized to 0!

Answer (score 5):

Your conception about how this works in Java might be misinformed - Java doesn't "allocate" a new `int` every time through a loop like that either. Primitive type variables like `int` aren't allocated on the Java heap, and the compiler will reuse the same local storage for each loop iteration.

On the other hand, if you call `new` anything in Java every time through a loop, then yes, a new object will be allocated every time. However, you're not doing that in this case. C also won't allocate anything from the heap unless you call `malloc` or similar (or in C++, `new`).

Answer (score 4):

Please note the difference between `automatic` and `dynamic` memory allocation. In Java only the latter exists.

This is automatic allocation:

```
int numWords = 0;
```

This is dynamic allocation:

```
int *pNumWords = malloc(sizeof(int));
*pNumWords = 0;
```

The dynamic allocation in C only happens explicitly (when you call `malloc` or its derivatives).

In your code, only the value is set to your variable, no new one is allocated.

Comment: So in other words... the symbol table (in most cases) created by the compiler will (or should) guarantee that primitive variables will be implicitly reused?

Comment: The terminology here is not quite correct.  Static allocation is for global variables.  In C, variables without linkage declared in function or block scope are said to be allocated "automatically" or have "automatic storage duration".  In Java, automatic storage allocation exists -- but it can only be used for primitives and references unless you have a *seriously* capable compiler/JIT.

Comment: @Dietrich Epp: I fixed it according to your remarks. I'm not that confident with Java and its capabilities. I hope it is more correct now.

Answer (score 3):

From a performance standpoint, it's not going to matter. (Variables map to registers or memory locations, so it has to be reused.)

<strike>From a logical standpoint, yes, it will be reused because you declared it outside the loop.</strike>

From a logical standpoint:

- `numWords` **will not** be reused in the **outer loop** because it is declared inside it.
- `numWords` **will** be reused in the **inner loop** because it isn't declared inside.

Comment: But during the `for` loop, will it get "redeclared" as it would in Java or would it be reused?

Comment: Unlike Java, where an object declaration implies dynamic resource allocation, spelling int i in C only means "store the variable somewhere" (with "somewhere" actually being on the stack, not in the dynamically allocated memory pool). but yes, it is redeclared in the sense that you can't expect it to save it's value between iterations. It can save it's state, but only as long as that particular memory address doesn't get overwritten by another variable, which is completely random.

Comment: "Declaring" in C only tells the compiler to reserve space for it on the stack or in a register. So there's no real concept of "redeclaring".

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: Java doesn't do any dynamic resource allocation for variables of primitive types (like `int`). `int i` in Java reserves a local variable slot at compile time, not runtime.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore: I see there are two loops here. I only noticed the inner loop. Will fix my answer.

Comment: This is why C89/ANSI states that all variables be declared at the top of a function.

Comment: @Peter: Incorrect.  C89 allows variables to be declared at the top of any block.

Answer (score 0):

The scope of the numWords variable is inside the for loop. Just as Java, you can only use the variable inside the loop, so theoretically its memory would have to be freed on exit - since it is also on the stack in your case.

Any good compiler however would use the same memory and simply re-set the variable to 0 on each iteration.

If you were using a `class` instead of an `int`, you would see the destructor being called every time the `for` loops.

Even consider this:

```
class A;

A* pA = new A;
delete pA;
pA = new A;
```

The two objects created here will probably reside at the same memory.

Answer (score -3):

It will be allocated every time through the loop (the compiler can optimize out that allocation)

```
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    int n = 0;
    printf("%d : %p\n", i, (void*)&n);
}
```

No guarantees all 100 lines will have the same address (though probably they will).

**Edit:** The [C99 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), in 6.2.4/5 says: `"[the object] lifetime extends from entry into the block with which it is associated until execution of that block ends in any way."` and, in 6.8.5/5, it says that the body of a `for` statement is in fact a block ... so the paragraph 6.2.4/5 applies.

Comment: +1 for giving code that can demonstrate instances where addresses will differ.  You can modify the code and add a giant malloc for say, 500k ints that will explicitly force an allocation at a different address (though not always).

Comment: @avgvstvs: No, you've still got the concept wrong. The stack and the heap do not interact in that way. No amount of `malloc()` will change the address of `n`.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill, well is there a way to reliably demonstrate changing the pointer address for the variable `n` in pmg's code?

Comment: @avgvstvs: No. The address of `n` is unlikely to change within a single call to that function. There may be a different address of `n` for a different call to the function, or if it calls itself recursively.

Comment: This cannot be demonstrated because it is not correct. `int n` is only allocated once in the loop, not each time through the loop. This is true for all settings of optimization. As Greg stated: the address will only change if called recursively or repeatedly from a different scope. With loop invocation in the same scope, `int n` here only allocates one int.

Comment: I thought I didn't have to fish out the relevant passage from the [C99 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf). See 6.2.4/5 ... `"[the object] lifetime extends from entry into the block with which it is associated until execution of that block ends in any way."` and 6.8.5/5 ... which specifies the loop body in a `for` statement is a block.

Comment: @pmg: But §6.2 does not state that 100 instances of n should be created in your example loop. The left hand side is ignored after the first time through the block and the right hand is executed each time. Try with a volatile RH like `random` or `time` -- still a single pointer address. If 100 instances of n would be created, this syntax would be legal: `{int n=0; int n=1;}` which it is not because of the redefinition of n.